# Using abstract base class for documentation purposes only

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class, code-documentation

I have a suite of similar classes called 'Executors', which are used in the [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). They are very simple classes:

```
class ExecutorA:
  def execute(self, data):
    pass

class ExecutorB:
  def execute(self, data):
    pass
```

The `execute()` functions of all executors need to behave in the same way, i.e. take data in a certain format and return data in another certain format. Due to duck-typing, there is no need to have a base class, so I didn't write one.

However, I am currently documenting my code using docstrings etc. and I thought it could be a good idea to document the data format requirements of the `execute()` functions in an abstract base class like so:

```
class Executor(ABC):
  def execute(self, data):
  """Process data in format xy and return data in format zy"""
    pass
```

My rationale is that I don't want to replicate the same documentation in every Executor class. Is this a common use case for ABC's?

**Clarification:**
I need to use python 3.6 because we are using RHEL and a newer python is not yet officially available.

Comment: You don't actually need classes to implement this in Python; functions are first-class objects and can be passed as arguments, rather than requiring an instance of an `Executor` class to carry the method.

Comment: @chepner This is true. My example simplifies quite a bit, in fact, I need the Executors to be classes because they hold some state.

Answer (score 3):

If it's for documentation / static type checking purposes only you can also use [`typing.Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) (starting with Python 3.8 and backported via [`typing_extensions`](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/)). This is used for [structural subtyping](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/) which doesn't require explicit inheritance. So you could do:

```
from typing import List, Protocol

class Executor(Protocol):
    def execute(self, data: List[float]) -> float:  # example type annotations
        """Reduce `data` to a single number."""
        ...

class ExecutorA:  # no base class required, it implements the protocol
    def execute(self, data: List[float]) -> float:
        return sum(data)

def do_work(worker: Executor,  # here we can use the Protocol class
            data: List[float]) -> float:
    return worker.execute(data)

do_work(ExecutorA(), [1., 2., 3.])  # this check passes
```

The doc string here is on the protocol class providing general information what the `execute` method does. Since `Executor` is used for type annotations users will be referred to the protocol class. If desired, additional information can be added to the implementations (`ExecutorA`, ...) as well, or the original doc string can be copied (this work can be done by a decorator).

The usage of abstract base classes is also a solution. ABCs allow for `isinstance` and `issubclass` checks and you can register additional classes that don't inherit the ABC explicitly.

Comment: Thank you for this solution! However, we use python 3.6, because we need to use RHEL, where a newer python is not (yet) natively available.

Comment: @arne The `Protocol` class was backported to Python 3.[5-7] by the [`typing_extensions`](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) package. So you can also install that package.

Comment: Do you know whether Sphinx understands `Protocol`s and can generate appropriate documentation on the `execute` function?

Comment: @arne Do you mean whether it will link a class that implements a Protocol to the Protocol's doc string? I don't think so, because even if a class implements a Protocol, there's no guarantee that you intended this to be "derived" from the Protocol base. Just like with type annotations where you explicitly require an object of type `Executor` (and hence the type checker can work out whether they are compatible), you would need to declare any doc string inheritance explicitly too. But you could use a class decorator which updates doc strings from the Protocol class.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I think that using an abstract base class for this is a reasonable option in Python 3.6. You may want to decorate `execute` as an [`@abstractmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod), but ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

Now if you want a little more control over your docstrings, you could make your own metaclass that inherits from [`ABCMeta`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta). For example, the following is a way to have "extensible" docstrings in the sense that your docstrings become format strings where `{pdoc}` will always be replaced by the documentation of your (first) parent class (if it exists).

```py
from abc import abstractmethod, ABCMeta
from inspect import getdoc

class DocExtender(ABCMeta):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, spec):
        for key, value in spec.items():
            doc = getattr(value, '__doc__', '{pdoc}')
            try:
                pdoc = getdoc(getattr(bases[0], key))
            except (IndexError, AttributeError):
                pdoc = ''
            try:
                value.__doc__ = doc.format(pdoc=pdoc)
            except AttributeError:
                pass
        return ABCMeta.__new__(cls, name, bases, spec)

class ExecutorBase(metaclass=DocExtender):
    @abstractmethod
    def execute(self, data):
        """
        Parent
        """
        pass

class Executor1(ExecutorBase):
    def execute(self, data):
        """
        {pdoc} - Child
        """
        return sum(data)

class Executor2(ExecutorBase):
    def execute(self, data):
        return sum(data)

print(getdoc(Executor1.execute))
# Parent - Child

print(getdoc(Executor2.execute))
# Parent
```

I am posting this mainly to illustrate the general concept; adjust as needed, obviously.

Comment: While I appreciate the opportunity to learn about metaclasses, which I didn't really understand before now, this seems a bit overkill just to create documentation.

Comment: You could also use a class decorator instead, that adjusts doc strings of functions.

Comment: @arne amen, +1 ;-)